# lwc handleSubmit field.value undefined...but it saves

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a custom edit form, it has a bunch of lightning-input-fields. One of which is a picklist called Promo__c that has a global value set.

When you hit submit it takes the code here

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.isSubmitting = !this.isSubmitting;
    if(this.checkIfNull()){
    const fields = event.detail.fields;

    fields.Cabinet__c = this.selectCab;
    fields.Brand__c = this.selectBrand;

    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    publish(this.messageContext,BLUESUBMI_LMS);
}
```

This works, saves the file to salesforce, if i wanted to i can go to the record, but after that i have a handleSuccess event

```
handleSuccess(event){
        this.template.querySelector('c-igt_-quote-line-items-table').refreshChild();

    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title : "Quote Worksheet",
        message : "New Quote Line Item Created  ",
        variant : "Success"
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    this.createOppLine(event);
```

and then it goes to createOppLine(event). I added a console.log here

```
createOppLine(event){
    let oli = { 'sobjectType' : 'OpportunityLineItem' };
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    console.log( ' create opp line event data ' + JSON.stringify(fields));
        oli.Product2Id = this.selectedProduct;

        if(this.revenueModel == 'For Sale'){
            oli.UnitPrice = fields.Min_or_Flat_Fee_Amount__c.value;
        } else {
            oli.Customer_RPU_Day__c = fields.Min_or_Flat_Fee_Amount__c.value;
            oli.UnitPrice = 0;
        }

        oli.Revenue_Model__c = this.revenueModel;
        oli.Promo__c = fields.Promo__c.value;
        oli.Quantity = fields.Quantity__c.value;
        oli.OpportunityId = this.parentOpp;
        oli.PricebookEntryId = this.priceBookEntry;

        createOppLineItem({ newOppLine : oli})
        .then(result => {
            this.newQuoteLineItem = null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.newQuoteLineItem = null;
            this.error = error;
        });
}
```

Now my user account has access to the Promo__c field (perm set). I select a value for promo and it saves....but when we get to

```
    oli.Promo__c = fields.Promo__c.value;
```

fields.Promo__c.value is undefined. If i comment out that line everything works. I have no idea why this is happening.

added debug log from the console.log above, as you can see Promo__c is not included in the fields.

```
create opp line event data {"Auto_TBD__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":false},"BLUE_To_Game_Theme__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"CRYSTAL_CURVE : test theme"},"Brand__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a9W0R0000004SG6UAM"},"Brand__r":{"displayValue":"test Brand","value":{"apiName":"Brand__c","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Id":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a9W0R0000004SG6UAM"},"Name":{"displayValue":null,"value":"test Brand"}},"id":"a9W0R0000004SG6UAM","lastModifiedById":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedDate":"2022-02-01T00:18:11.000Z","recordTypeId":"012000000000000AAA","recordTypeInfo":null,"systemModstamp":"2022-02-01T00:18:11.000Z"}},"Build_Type__c":{"displayValue":"Replacement","value":"Replacement"},"Business_Segment__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Cabinet_Style__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Cabinet_Type__c":{"displayValue":"Excess Inventory","value":"Excess Inventory"},"Cabinet__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a9X0R0000004I0vUAE"},"Cabinet__r":{"displayValue":"CRYSTAL_CURVE","value":{"apiName":"Cabinet__c","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Id":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a9X0R0000004I0vUAE"},"Name":{"displayValue":null,"value":"CRYSTAL_CURVE"}},"id":"a9X0R0000004I0vUAE","lastModifiedById":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedDate":"2022-02-01T00:20:26.000Z","recordTypeId":"012000000000000AAA","recordTypeInfo":null,"systemModstamp":"2022-02-01T00:20:26.000Z"}},"Conv_from_Trade_Show__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":false},"Converted_Opportunity__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Converted_Opportunity__r":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"CreatedBy":{"displayValue":"Tony Rissone","value":{"apiName":"User","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Id":{"displayValue":null,"value":"0051O00000D0r51QAB"},"Name":{"displayValue":null,"value":"Tony Rissone"}},"id":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedById":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedDate":"2022-02-01T00:02:24.000Z","recordTypeId":null,"recordTypeInfo":null,"systemModstamp":"2022-02-04T16:18:48.000Z"}},"CreatedById":{"displayValue":null,"value":"0051O00000D0r51QAB"},"CreatedDate":{"displayValue":"2/4/2022 12:49 PM","value":"2022-02-04T20:49:57.000Z"},"Current_Brain_Box__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Current_Panel__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Current_Reels__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Custom_Laminate__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Custom_Stand__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Discount__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Display__c":{"displayValue":"LCD","value":"LCD"},"File_Number__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Form_Factor__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Button_Panel__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Product__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Product__r":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Reel__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Theme_Denom__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Theme_Formula__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Theme_Manual__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Theme__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Theme__r":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"From_Theme_text__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"GTECH__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":0},"Game_Title__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Generic_Product__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"INC_REP_CONV__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"REP"},"Incremental__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":false},"Juris_Type__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Laminate_Name_and_Manufacturer__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"LastModifiedBy":{"displayValue":"Tony Rissone","value":{"apiName":"User","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Id":{"displayValue":null,"value":"0051O00000D0r51QAB"},"Name":{"displayValue":null,"value":"Tony Rissone"}},"id":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedById":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedDate":"2022-02-01T00:02:24.000Z","recordTypeId":null,"recordTypeInfo":null,"systemModstamp":"2022-02-04T16:18:48.000Z"}},"LastModifiedById":{"displayValue":null,"value":"0051O00000D0r51QAB"},"LastModifiedDate":{"displayValue":"2/4/2022 12:50 PM","value":"2022-02-04T20:50:00.000Z"},"Machine_Configuration__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Mapped_Quantity__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":1},"Mapped_Terms__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Min_or_Flat_Fee_Amount__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":42},"Name":{"displayValue":null,"value":"GT-129181"},"New_Opening_Expansion__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":false},"Notes__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"test"},"OppProductRef__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"OppProduct_Link__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"<a href=\"/\" target=\"_blank\">Click Here</a>"},"Opportunity_Product__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Opportunity_Product__r":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Optional_Setup_Software__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Parent_Opportunity__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Parent_Opportunity__r":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Payment_Terms__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Paytable_Percent__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Player_Tracking__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Plex__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Poker__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Printer__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Quantity__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":1},"RecordType":{"displayValue":"Premium New Build","value":{"apiName":"RecordType","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Id":{"displayValue":null,"value":"01214000001NcbsAAC"},"Name":{"displayValue":"Premium New Build","value":"Premium New Build"}},"id":"01214000001NcbsAAC","lastModifiedById":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedDate":"2022-02-04T16:50:36.000Z","recordTypeId":null,"recordTypeInfo":null,"systemModstamp":"2022-02-04T16:50:36.000Z"}},"RecordTypeId":{"displayValue":null,"value":"01214000001NcbsAAC"},"Record_Type_Name__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Replacing__c":{"displayValue":"Yes: with New Build","value":"Yes: with New Build"},"Sales_Price__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Sales_Toolkit__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a4W0R000000NL4cUAG"},"Sales_Toolkit__r":{"displayValue":"ST-066660","value":{"apiName":"Sales_Toolkit__c","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Id":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a4W0R000000NL4cUAG"},"Name":{"displayValue":null,"value":"ST-066660"},"RecordTypeId":{"displayValue":null,"value":"01214000001NcbrAAC"}},"id":"a4W0R000000NL4cUAG","lastModifiedById":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedDate":"2022-02-04T20:50:01.000Z","recordTypeId":"01214000001NcbrAAC","recordTypeInfo":{"available":true,"defaultRecordTypeMapping":false,"master":false,"name":"EGM Build","recordTypeId":"01214000001NcbrAAC"},"systemModstamp":"2022-02-04T20:50:01.000Z"}},"Screen_Type_From__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Seats__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Serial_Number_Manual__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"0"},"Serial_Number__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"0"},"Sign__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Signage__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Signature_Required__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Slant_Configuration__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Spare_Cash_Boxes__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Standard_Build_or_Laminate__c":{"displayValue":"Standard Build","value":"Standard Build"},"Stands__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Terms__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Theme_Code__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"125"},"To_Actual_Theme__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a090R00000EYeOYQA1"},"To_Actual_Theme__r":{"displayValue":"test theme","value":{"apiName":"Theme__c","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Id":{"displayValue":null,"value":"a090R00000EYeOYQA1"},"Name":{"displayValue":null,"value":"test theme"}},"id":"a090R00000EYeOYQA1","lastModifiedById":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedDate":"2022-02-01T00:18:39.000Z","recordTypeId":"012000000000000AAA","recordTypeInfo":null,"systemModstamp":"2022-02-01T00:18:39.000Z"}},"To_Button_Panel__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"To_Reel__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"To_Theme_Denom__c":{"displayValue":"0.01","value":"0.01"},"To_Theme__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":"01t5Y00000DY3JZQA1"},"To_Theme__r":{"displayValue":"CRYSTAL_CURVE : test theme","value":{"apiName":"Product2","childRelationships":{},"fields":{"Id":{"displayValue":null,"value":"01t5Y00000DY3JZQA1"},"Name":{"displayValue":null,"value":"CRYSTAL_CURVE : test theme"},"RecordTypeId":{"displayValue":null,"value":"0125Y000001PPdPQAW"}},"id":"01t5Y00000DY3JZQA1","lastModifiedById":"0051O00000D0r51QAB","lastModifiedDate":"2022-02-04T17:32:23.000Z","recordTypeId":"0125Y000001PPdPQAW","recordTypeInfo":{"available":true,"defaultRecordTypeMapping":false,"master":false,"name":"Trade Sale","recordTypeId":"0125Y000001PPdPQAW"},"systemModstamp":"2022-02-04T17:32:23.000Z"}},"To_Theme_del__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Top_Box__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Topper_Conversion__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":null},"Topper__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":true},"Use_Existing_Customer_Profile__c":{"displayValue":null,"value":true}}
```

but here's the edit form package prior to submit where the Promo__c is showing.

```
 fields prior to submit and AFTER to custom additions : {"To_Theme_Denom__c":"0.01","Promo__c":"EM - Content Promotion – LAC","Min_or_Flat_Fee_Amount__c":"54","Quantity__c":1,"Discount__c":null,"Standard_Build_or_Laminate__c":"Standard Build","Incremental__c":false,"Use_Existing_Customer_Profile__c":true,"Topper__c":true,"Notes__c":"test","Cabinet__c":"a9X5Y000000Y1xUUAS","Brand__c":"a9W5Y000000Pwf2UAC","To_Theme__c":"01t5Y00000DY1pRQAT","Sales_Toolkit__c":"a4W5Y000002e5m4UAA","To_Actual_Theme__c":"a095Y00001BqV7cQAF"}
```

added createOppLineItem() apex class

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createOppLineItem(OpportunityLineItem newOppLine){
        insert newOppLine;
    }
```

edit: any admins know how i can give the bounty to glls? He inspired me to give field access to the picklist at the profile level. Which solved the issue

Comment: which is undefined? fields ? fields.Promo__c ? or fields.Promo__c.value ?

Comment: fields.Promo__c.value

Comment: can you debug and let us know what `fields.Promo__c` returns?

Comment: @glls added the debug log, funnily enough the Promo__c field isn't even there.

Comment: so then Promo__c is undefined =) - you also want to probably check, when you save the record, what the JSON payload looks like before saving.

Comment: Well i would think if the first record saves then the payload includes the field. I go to the record and the field has a value stored. but i'll put that in and check

Comment: @glls Promo is there in the payload prior to save but not after.

Comment: is createOppLineItem invoked from an apex class?

Comment: Is the submit(fields) for the record-edit-form working correctly? it returns the id of the newly created record, correct?

Comment: @glls the submit(fields) works, it is successful and it creates the record. Then on onsuccess the handleSuccess event has the record ID, it has field values, but for some reason one field is missing it's not in the log within event.detail.fields, the Promo__c ....field which also happens to be a global picklist if that matters.

Comment: @glls if you ctrl+f on this page you can see Promo__c in one of my logs, but not in the after success log.

Comment: i'm not familair enough with global picklist value saving, however, if there were a formating error or somehting, usually, the record ui api will throw an error, out of curiosity, if you set the filed visibility at a profile level, instead of the perm set, does it change anything? (should work with perm set though)

Comment: @glls so i added field access at the profile level as well at it worked. It seems that for restricted picklists there's some strange behavior that occurs if access is only granted at the permission set level, access must also be given at the profile level

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked out =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is considered a Fix, however, sometimes, when experiencing FLS issues even though my permission set should technically grant me access to it I check the following to things:

- Make sure that the profile has the FLS that my permission set is supposed to grant my user.
- Ensure that the Layout my profile has access to has the field in it.

Comment: honestly it's some weird behavior. Only with restricted picklists has been a thing.

Comment: I did some further testing. It being on the layout doesn't matter, what matters is if access to the restricted picklist is granted at the profile level.